# Can't get GetPositionFromPoint to work well (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to use the GetPositionFromPoint, and in the documentation it talks about the snapToText bool which, if false, *"returns null if point is not inside a character's bounding box"*. Anyway, I am receiving always a null TextPointer, even when my Point is on a character. I leave my code here, I am using a checkbox (called "check") to see if the TextPointer is null or not, and it is always unchecked:

```
Point posicion = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
TextPointer posAhora = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromPoint(posicion, false);
if(posAhora != null)
{
   check.IsChecked = true;
}
else
{
   check.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, question: In what event or how are you fire that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are interested in the coordinates inside a specific control, then you must calculate the position relative to this control. If calculate the position relative to some other control positions won't match with the target control.

Example: you have a small `TextBox` inside a big `Window` and you are interested in the coordinates inside the `TextBox`. What you did, you calculated all positions relative to the big `Window`. Now let's say the `TextBox` with dimensions of 12 * 12 is positioned in the bottom right corner of a 32 * 32 window at the position *x=20;y=20*.

```
 ________________
|                | <--- MainWindow 32 * 32
|                |
|           _____|
|          |     |
|          |  P  | <--- TextBox 12 * 12 (x=20;y=20)
|__________|_____|

p = pointer position
```

The mouse pointer is now in the center of the `TextBox` and you calculate:

```
p = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

`p` is calculated relative to the big 32 * 32 window and evaluates to *x=26;y=26*, which is the result of your current and wrong calculations.
When you use this coordinates to look for text in the `TextBox` you are obviously out of bounds (in this example) as the `TextBox` dimension is only 12 * 12.

Now the correct calculation of the position:

```
p = Mouse.GetPosition(TextBox);
```

`p` is now calculated relative to the `TextBox` and evaluates to *x=6;y=6*. This coordinates are now inside the 12 * 12 bounds of the `TextBox`, where you may hit the box of rendered text.

---

The following example shows the correct implementation of a `CheckBox` that gets checked when the mouse pointer is over the input text of a `RichtextBox`:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox"/>

    <!-- Enter some text and move the mouse over the text -->
    <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnMouseMove(e);

  var relativeMousePosition = e.GetPosition(this.RichTextBox);
  this.CheckBox.IsChecked = this.RichTextBox.GetPositionFromPoint(relativeMousePosition , false) != null;
}
```