# I cannot add elements to my GUI if I have a chart from LiveCharts

Tags: wpf, livecharts

Now the chart can not resize anymore I think is has to do with the *RowDefinitions* (*) I understand that takes the space left, but I want to put some other stuff below my chart. If I understood correctly you have to put your rows and columns in the order you want your elements

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
          Orientation="Horizontal"
          Margin="0,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="ComboBox1 Label" />
            <ComboBox />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="ComboBox2 Label" />
            <ComboBox />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
          Orientation="Horizontal"
          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
          Margin="0,0,12,0">
        <RadioButton Content="Text" />
        <RadioButton Content="Text" />
        <RadioButton Content="Text" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock Text="Button Label" />
        <Button Content="Text" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--CartesianChart Grid.Row="2" 
              Grid.Column="0" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3" /-->

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Button Label" />
        <Button Content="Text" />
    </StackPanel>

    <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="129,136.2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

[I wanted something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxvtu.png)

Comment: If you use an unorganized `Grid` (without columns and rows) everything draws on top of each other. Your chart currently hides everything. I don't know how your layout is supposed to be like. But you must use rows and columns or use a simple `StackPanel`. If something stops working always run your application in debug mode to see the exception which actually stops the application. Then come back and post the error message here and if possible the context and line of code where the exception was thrown.

Comment: [Panel Elements and Custom Layout Behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout#panel-elements-and-custom-layout-behaviors).

Comment: @BionicCode thanks, I have tried with the _StackPanel_, but seems it does not work, it does nos show the full chart and when I resize the chart, the program runs, but not as expected. The debug mode does not seem to show any message

Comment: @BionicCode I have posted something similar to what I want would it be better to do it with a _Grid_ or _StackPanel_ ? Thank you

Comment: how do you resize the chart and _what_ does not behave as expected? What do you expect? Need more details. Do you know how to layout a Grid?

Comment: @BionicCode I resize my chart with height and width inside the XAML; I expect the functioning of my program, which is carthesian chart with predetermined values and if you click at one point, you can drag it all around the chart. When I add the chart to the XAML at first it occupies the whole space from the window and that is  when it works. Otherwise you can move the point but it does not follow the path from mouse. I do not know how to layout a Grid

Comment: If I understand you right everything works except dragging points?

Comment: @BionicCode yes that is right

Comment: Then show the relevant code for the dragging operations.

Comment: @BionicCode I have updated the code with the relevant for dragging operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the screen point relative to the `CartesianChart` otherwise the position returned is relative to the `MainWindow`(because you passed `this`).
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61373938/3141792) for a little more detailed explanation.

I also simplified your code:

```
public ObservablePoint MovingPoint { get; set; }

private void ChartOnDataClick(object sender, ChartPoint p) //click on point
{
  var observablePointIndex = this.diagram.Series[0].Values
    .GetPoints(this.diagram.Series[0].Model.View)
    .ToList()
    .IndexOf(p);
  this.MovingPoint = this.diagram.Series[0].Values[observablePointIndex] as ObservablePoint;
}

private void ChartOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.MovingPoint == null
      || e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    return;

  Point newPoint = this.diagram.ConvertToChartValues(e.GetPosition(this.diagram));
  this.MovingPoint.X = newPoint.X;
  this.MovingPoint.Y = newPoint.Y;
}

private void ChartOnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  this.MovingPoint = null; // deactivate point moving
}
```

---

**Example `Grid`**

Note that a row/column height/width of `*` will force the row/column to stretch to occupy max space when the parent e.g. a `Window` grows. `*` is the default value. A size of `Auto` forces the row/column to adjust its size to the content.

When using rows/columns it is possible to let a control stretch across multiple rows/columns by specifying `Grid.RowSpan`/`Grid.ColumnSpan`.

To allow the chart to grow, the row's height that contains the chart is set to `*`. All other rows are set to `Auto`.

To allow the chart to stretch across the full `Grid`, the `Grid.ColumnSpan` is set to *3* (because the `Grid` contains three columns).

The following example is based on your posted image:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              Margin="0,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="ComboBox1 Label" />
      <ComboBox />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="ComboBox2 Label" />
      <ComboBox />
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Margin="0,0,12,0">
    <RadioButton Content="Text" />
    <RadioButton Content="Text" />
    <RadioButton Content="Text" />
  </StackPanel>

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock Text="Button Label" />
    <Button Content="Text" />
  </StackPanel>

  <CartesianChart Grid.Row="2" 
                  Grid.Column="0" 
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock Text="Button Label" />
    <Button Content="Text" />
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BionicCode

Comment: Do you know how can I resize my chart as my window resizes? I just want the chart to resize

Comment: If you add the chart to a Grid it should resize automatically. Your grid should have 2 rows (at least). Set the Height of the last row which contains the chart to `*`. All other rows should have the height set to `Auto`. Set Height and Width of the chart to `Auto` (or simply don't set the dimensions at all).

Comment: I fixed some typos in my code example. I replaced two references to `this.CartesianChart` with `this.diagram`.

Comment: thank you very much! I really appreciate your help, I am still having toruble with the resize of the chart, well now the chart resizes, but other elements change their size too

Comment: I cant really help unless you show the XAML code. Please edit your question and post the relevant grid and controls that are giving you trouble.

Comment: Thank you. I now can see that you are creating the layout totally wrong. It looks like you are arranging the controls using the `Margin`. This is why your layout is messed up. Please take 10 minutes and read this link: [Grid Layout in WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/grid-layout-in-wpf/). It shows you how to organize controls in a `Grid` using columns and rows. Please try to apply this knowledge to your `Grid` layout. Comeback and let me know about your progress. I can help, but it is important that you get a basic understanding how to use the `Grid`. It's quite simple.

Comment: Another important panel ist the `StackPanel`. You typically arrange controls by combining a `Grid` which can contains multiple `StackPanel`. [StackPanel in WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/stackpanel-in-wpf/). You can use this panel to group labels and buttons or labels and comboboxes etc.. it is very useful. Contents inside the `StackPanel` won't resize when the parent e.g. a `grid` resizes. Contents of a `grid` usually stretch automatically to occupy the maximum space.

Comment: thank you very much. I just have one question I have updated the XAML code, but now the chart can not resize the one thing I did not completely understand is, if I can add some elements below my chart, so that the row of my chart is not the last and how would the RowDefinition = "*" work in this case or what could I do?

Comment: A height or width of `*` means that the row/column will take the max available space. If  a `grid` has two rows and `Grid.Height` is _10_ and the first row has a height of _3_ them the second row which has a height of `*` will have an effective height of _7_. If you want the chart to grow when the Grid's parent grows than set the row that contains the chart to `*` and every other row to `Auto`. You `Grid` layout is too complicated. I updated my answer and build a `Grid` layout based on your image. It contains an additional row below the chart to show you the resize behavior.

Comment: Just replace the chart with yours.

Comment: It is still not working, I do not know why. This time the problem is the chart does not sizes as the window I tried to do it this way.

Comment: I think this time has to do with the chart, but I do not know where is the error

Comment: I have just tested the grid (my answer) and it works. The chart grows when the window (grid) grows. Your chart can't resize. First, good that you have posted your current code. I can see that you have set `Height` and `Width` of the chart. Also don't set `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`. Both are `Stretch'  by default, whidch is right because you want the chart to occupy full remaining space. Remove those four attributes and try again.

Comment: When setting `Width` or `Height` explicitly to other than `Auto` (which is the default value), controls can't grow/shirnk into the related dimension as it is fixed.

Comment: I did not know that, it was that. Thank you very much

Comment: I am glad that I could help. Have fun with your project. WPF is difficult to learn, because of the details. So you must read the docs from time to time. Some must know is [Styles and templates in WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview). See [Control authoring overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview) and [Data binding overview in WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview). Just take your 15 min time to read and try what you  just read.